# Jquery requestFullScreen is not the same as pressing F11 in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on request full screen in IE 11

The problem is , calling jquery requestFullScreen will stripe my content into half of the width, while if I press the F11 or open full screen manually at the browser it work fine.

I wonder is there any Bug caused by IE requestFullScreen, as other browser work fine

```
function launchIntoFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Here is the demo link:

http://www.pure-yoga.com/hongkong/pick_a_class

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the plugin seems fixed the problem

https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/

thanks

Comment: in fact it doesn't -that's no full screen mode, and it's also disabling the native F11 key functionality

Comment: @BekimBacaj How is it not full screen mode? When using it in Chrome, it acts exactly as if F11 has been pressed, unlike the fullscreen API which for some bizarre reason makes my whole screen black. It also doesn't block the usual functionality of F11 - for me, it can still be used to enter and exit fullscreen.